# Why faulty, old CRT TV produce ozone

Tags: tv, lightning, arc, ozone

I have an old CRT TV which had to be switched ON for half an hour or so for the picture to stop being blurry and be 'viewable'. During this initial warm-up time there was a 'static' like noise coming from the TV which was not from the speakers. Also there was this weird smell which filled the room which I now suspect was ozone. I couldn't find any visible arcing although the sound was similar to one. Had it repaired (faulty transformer they said) and the both the sound and the smell went away. How is possible for the device to produce ozone? I understand it requires a very high amount of energy, equivalent to lightning, for ozone to be produced in nature. How can the small voltage and current (compared to lightning) levels in home do this which normally requires such a very large amount of energy ?

Comment: There is nothing "small voltage" when you're talking about CRT displays. Large TV sets require in excess of 20kV (twenty thousand volts) for the CRT to operate correctly. Even old B/W sets operate into the thousands of volts. Plenty of ozone potential.

Answer (score 1):

CRT TVs use the flyback transformer to generate voltage levels of about 20 to 30 kilovolts to accelerate electrons inside the tube.

That is much more than the about 2 to 10 kilovolts required to produce ozone.

Any exposed high voltage can create a corona discharge that produces ozone.

Answer (score 0):

The flyback transformer used to supply the anode in the CRT boosts the voltage to 10's of kilovolts, and if there's any insulation degradation or even contamination around connections you can get arcing or corona, which can generate ozone.

Answer (score 0):

Ozone is produced as a result of arc discharge or corona discharge (a consequence of high electric field gradient) -- a lightning bolt has immense energy and thus produces a large amount of ozone, while your TV may have had small arcs (consistent with the static-like sound) producing a smaller amount of ozone. These are the result of a malfunction in a flyback transformer, which produces large voltages (but low current, hence modest energy) necessary for the CRT to operate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the FOCUS grid had the wrong voltage, compared to the electron gun direct or indirect(heated) cathode.

And some leakage currents thru some resistors caused an incorrect voltage drop, providing the unacceptable FOCUS potential.

With the leakage now cured, you get a good picture promptly.